# Is Kafka 0.7.2 compatible with Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, bigdata, apache-kafka, java-6

I need to migrate a project from jdk6 to jdk8 and thus I need to check compatibility of libraries we are using. Is there someone who actually worked with Kafka 0.7.2? Is it compatible with jdk8? 
I have doubts because the team behind Apache Kafka doesn't seem to care about backwards compatibility.

Comment: why not just try it?

Answer (score 0):

Apache's team have nothing to do with Java's backwards compatibility (if indeed you're updating Java, not Kafka).

If 0.7.2 works for you currently, it's unlikely that it would break on Java 8.